# Is changing the size of a struct a breaking change in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, struct, cil

Just curious, is changing the size of a struct/value type a breaking change in C#? Structs tend to be more sensitive in terms of memory layout since altering them directly affects the size of arrays/other structs. Are there any examples of code that breaks, either binary-wise or source-wise, after the layout of a struct in a library it uses is changed?

NOTE: By "breaks," I mean it fails to compile at all or the IL is invalidated. So for example I wouldn't consider this a breaking change:

```
// My.Library v1
public struct MyStruct {}

// My.Library v2
public struct MyStruct { int _field; }

// App code
using My.Library;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf<MyStruct>()); // before printed 1, now prints 4
```

because it still runs.

Comment: Are you using InteropServices to interact with unmanaged code? If so the answer is yes, it is a breaking change. If no, the answer is more nuanced.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question... You recompiled the Assembly, so everything should be OK ?

Comment: The jitter hides a lot of sins.  Structure sizes play no role at build time, only runtime.  Having an uninitialized field might be surprising.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing size by adding fields is ok for strictly managed code.

Adding field(s) is non-breaking change as code will be re-JIT-ed with the new type and all allocations will use correct size. Since it is value type the new fields will be properly initialized with empty values anyway.

Removing/changing types of existing fields(s) or properties is definitely breaking change.

Value types are sealed - so no other libraries can derive from that type - so unlike classes they can't create problems with "this derived class did not implement a new virtual property/interface method".

Note: if a value type is used for interop or any other kind of binary serialization outside of your control than any change is breaking.

I.e. someone else used `MyLib.Point {int x;int y;}` to save a list of points with binary serialization to a file. If now "MyLib" adds a new field to `MyLib.Point` than the serialized data no longer can be read with binary serialization. Similar issue with native interop.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, source code incompatibilities are definitely possible, even in strictly managed code, if you add a new field. Taking your example, this compiles with version 1 but not version 2:

```
MyStruct s;
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

The reason is that C# allows a struct local to be used if all the fields have been assigned values. In version 1, there are no fields so `s` is "definitely assigned". However if a field is added in version 2, even if it is private, then this no longer compiles because `s` is no longer definitely assigned.

This case should be binary compatible since the CLR guarantees initialization of fields to their default values.

Jared Parsons had a [good blog post](http://blog.paranoidcoding.com/2016/02/15/are-private-members-api-surface.html) on the subject of private fields in structs where he details other cases where changing private implementation details would be dangerous (for unsafe code) or breaking.

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks for the blog post by the way, was an interesting read.